# How to catch 'recv timed out' errors for Perl MongoDB::Cursor?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I've got a Perl program emitting these messages via cron:

```
recv timed out (60000 ms) at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8/MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 251.
recv timed out (60000 ms) at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8/MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 251.
recv timed out (60000 ms) at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8/MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 251.
```

I've taken the following steps to mitigate:

eval block around $collection->find(...)

eval block around $cursor->next()

connection query_timeout value 60000

connection timeout 1000

Timeouts are not a surprise because the server is under high load. But I would like to smartly capture the timeouts and exit gracefully.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I've determined that the recv timeouts are definitely occurring on the **$cursor->next()** call.

```
# doesn't capture
{   
    local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { return; };    
    $doc_ref = $cursor->next();
};

# doesn't capture
eval { $doc_ref = $cursor->next(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably make an exit call, not a diie, so it is not catcheable by eval. Try Test::Trap.

> Primarily (but not exclusively) for use in test scripts: A block eval on steroids, configurable and extensible, but by default trapping (Perl) STDOUT, STDERR, warnings, exceptions, would-be exit codes, and return values from boxed blocks of test code.

```
  use Test::Trap;

  my @r = trap { some_code(@some_parameters) };
  if ( $trap->exit != 0 ){
    say 'Expecting &some_code to exit with not 0';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, it is a `die`, and you can trap it. Once I wrote an [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) + [EV](https://metacpan.org/module/EV) daemon which cheats death (*evil laugh*) by respawning via this dirty trick:

```
use FindBin qw($Script);
use EV;
$EV::DIED = sub { warn $@; exec $^X, $Script, qw(restart) };
```

There is also an universal `die` trap, described by brian d foy in his [Override die with END or CORE::GLOBAL::die](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1310) article:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { warn "I'm sorry, Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that" };
```